# How to call a script that expects $_POST from inside a function

Tags: php, post

My `script.php` accepts `$_POST` input and echos a string.

```
$theinput = $_POST['theinput'];
$output = //some processing;
echo $output;
```

I need the same code in another function in a different file `second.php` and don't want to repeat the code. But the first script `script.php` expects input as `$_POST`. My input in the function is not `$_POST` just a regular parameter.

```
function processinput($someinput){
   //run the same script above, 
   //just the input is a parameter, not a `$_POST`
}
```

Any ideas how to do that? Is it possible to simulate a `$_POST` or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always assign values to $_POST just as if it is an array. A bit of a hack-job, and you are probably better off changing the function to take the value in as a parameter, but it will work.

```
$_POST['theinput'] = "value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) method?

second.php:

```
function processinput($someinput){
  $output = //some processing;
  echo $output;
}
```

script.php:

```
include_once('second.php'); // second.php contains processinput()
$theinput = $_POST['theinput'];
processinput($theinput);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function processinput($someinput){ 
   //I need to call the above script and give it  
   //the same input `$someinput` which is not a `$_POST` anymore 
   $results = strrev($someinput);
   return $results;
} 

$theinput = $_POST['theinput'];
$output = processinput($theinput);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not sure I understand the answer. The function and the script are not in the same file. Also the function is calling the `$_POST` script, not the other way around

Comment: -1: this makes no sense; reversing a string (`strrev`) has nothing to do with the question as far as I can tell.

Comment: Noting that it is for demonstrative purposes helps, thanks for clearing it up.